# Use code-style font

Tags: fonts, code

Just a quick question, I want parts of my document to be on this particular font which resembles a code, like this with `mclust` and `FactoMineR`:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: `\texttt{like this}`

Comment: In case you're curious what the "tt" in `\texttt` standds for: it's an abbreviation for "teletype". Teletype (telex) machines used monospaced fonts to print their output. To this day (in English at least -- not sure about other languages), monospaced fonts are also called teletype fonts -- hence the "tt" abbreviation.

Comment: Better `\newcommand*\paquet[1]{\texttt{#1}}` and then `Paquets: \paquet{mclust}, \paquet{FactoMinerR}, xtable`...

Comment: @Manuel Even better `\newcommand*\paquet{\texttt}`.  That saves one step of tokenization.  (BTW `\texttt` is a `long` macro, so `\newcommand\paquet[1]{\texttt{#1}}` should at least be `long` as well, i.e. no `*`).

Comment: @HenriMenke Might not be clear for new users, but yes :) And about the `\long`ness, well, here that's precisely what's better, the interface limits that, since packet is going to be used over words.

Answer (score 2):

Simply type:

```
Paquets: \texttt{mclust}, \textt{FactoMinerR}, xtable
```